# In ReactJs when use onclick fuction with setState, how to pass parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my case, im using few buttons and when a button is clicked, there should be a change in view. for the view i am using same panel for each button click and the change will be apply on heading of the panel( company name). To change the name I am sending parameter with Onclick method like below.

```
class View extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state ={
            message: <Content name="ABC"/>
        }
    }

    changeStateMSG(prevStep,props){
        this.setState({
            message:<Content name={this.props.name}/>
        })
    }
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className="row">
            <div className="mr-sm-3">
            <div style={{ width: '18rem', marginTop: '20px' }}>

              <Button onClick={() => this.changeStateMSG(this.props.name="XYZ")} variant="secondary" size="lg" block >
                    Omobio
              </Button>

              <div className="mr-sm-9">
                  <p>{this.state.message}</p>
              </div>
```

....
when i pass parameter like above (this.props.name="XYZ") i am getting error as "TypeError: Cannot add property name, object is not extensible". Hope some can help me

Comment: Avoid storing components (`Content`) in the state.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the `props` as the react docs says

#### [Props are Read-Only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)

> Whether you declare a component as a function or a class, **it must never modify its own props**

You should just pass `"XYZ"`. or you can pass a object with `this.props` with `name:'XYZ'` using spread operator.

```
onClick={() => this.changeStateMSG({...this.props,name:"XYZ"})}
```

And change your function which this

```
changeStateMSG(prevStep){
        this.setState({
            message:<Content name={prevState.name}/>
        })
    }
```

If you don't want all the `props` object inside your function then just pass `"XYZ"`.

```
onClick={() => this.changeStateMSG("XYZ")}
```

And change you function to this

```
changeStateMSG(name){
   this.setState({
            message:<Content name={name}/>
   })
}
```

Comment: Thank You Maheer :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the documentation? I believe the error clearly states that you can not add property to the `this.props`.

You can pass the arguments just with this statement, like in a normal function execution.

```
<Button 
  onClick={() => this.changeStateMSG("value_first_argument", "value_ second_argument")}
  variant="secondary"
  size="lg"
  block >
  Omobio
</Button>
```

And your function definition should look like,

```
changeStateMSG(prevStep, props){
        this.setState({
            message:<Content name={this.props.name}/>
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you have to pass the `props.name` to `changeStateMSG` function when you can access it from that function? Just simple call that in `changeStateMSG` and remove parameters you don't use.

```
changeStateMSG(){
    this.setState({
        message:<Content name={this.props.name}/>
    })
}

...
onClick={this.changeStateMSG}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is function this.changeStateMSG(this.props.name="XYZ").
Did U pass variable prevStep.
U pass like this  (this.props.name="XYZ") is wrong way.
Should edit:

```
render() { 
     const prevStep = 1;
     return ( 
        <div className="row">
          <div className="mr-sm-3">
            <div style={{ width: '18rem', marginTop: '20px' }}>

              <Button onClick={() => this.changeStateMSG(prevStep, {name:'XYZ'})}  variant="secondary" size="lg" block >
                    Omobio
              </Button>
```